# Is there a way to uniquely find the ios device with number

Tags: ios, cordova

I need to store the unique number of a IOS device like android IMEI number. Is there a phonegap code to take that number.

Comment: There is a way to get Serial Number of device, but the way is using private apis, so if you use that then apple will not allow you to upload your app on appstore

Comment: @MehulThakkar , but there should be a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS you can't access to the IMEI, at least not with public APIs.

But you can use the "identifier for vendor", it will return an identifier unique for that user in all your apps.

You can use my phonegap plugin https://github.com/jcesarmobile/IDFVPlugin

Comment: are the device.uuid and ios identifierForVendor are same?

Comment: no, device.uuid is created with a CFUUID, it's persisted by cordova but changes if you delete the app, and it's different in every app you create.

Comment: Identifier for vendor should be the same for all your apps (it's different on ad-hoc distribution if the apps bundle identifiers don't have the same root) , and shouldn't change after uninstalls (it changes on unistalls when you are in development, but it doesn't change if the app was installed from the app store according to my tests) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor